# Higgs bundles and stable vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathcal M_X(r,0,K_X)$ be tha moduli space of semistable Higgs bundles over a smooth irreducible algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$. And let $E$ be a stable vector bundle of rank $r$ and degree $0$. Then clearly we have an injection $$H^0(X,E\otimes E^*\otimes K_X)\rightarrow \mathcal M_X(r,0,K_X)$$

> Is this map a closed immersion? Is it proper?

Thanks

Comment: It the coarse moduli space, not the stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer to my question!

We can deduce easly that if this map is closed immersion, then $E$ is very stable vector bundle (because in this case, the Hitchin map is finite). Hence if $E$ is stable non very stable vector bundle (there exist of course such vector bundles) then we deduce that the above map couldn't be closed immersion.